# Get inserted record in Waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

How to get the inserted record in Waterline?

*Note: I am using sails.js*

**My code :**

```
            record=MyModel.create({
                ...
            }).exec(function createdFile(err, _record){
              ...
              return _record;
            });
```

`record` is always `undefined` but it is inserted in the DB, I want to return the inserted record in json to the client after the insert. (`res.json({'message':jsonx(record)});`).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record will be undefined as you are probably using the value prior to the callback completing. You need to reference _record as this is the created record within the callback after the create. You will need to nest inside to use the returned record e.g. do `res.view('page',{message: _record});`

Example usage: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/waterline/models/create.md

```
record=MyModel.create({

        }).exec(function createdFile(err, _record){

          return res.json({message: _record});
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you can also chain .then() instead of .exec() if you want for it to finish the query then pass the data through to the callback.

```js
var record = MyModel.create({ 
   }).then(function(err, _record){
          return res.json({message: _record});
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Awesome :)